# Where are the bioinformatics questions in other SE sites? (Community wiki)

Tags: discussion, scope

*Subject: This page is specified for discussion for feature development to  link this site  with other sites those too containing bioinformatics question.*

Related: [should we import questions from other SE sites?](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/migrating-bioinformatics-questions-from-other-se-sites)

There are many other sites within Stackexchange Network that contains bioinformatics question. Some could not be transferred by design because they [crossed 60 day age](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/migrating-bioinformatics-questions-from-other-se-sites/22#22), and for the other question there may exist some-other problem, so universal migration could be impossible.  to filter all bioinformatics question

But as an alternative solution to migration,  if we want to easily browse/filter those relevant (since they are  bioinformatics questions) while using only bioinformatics SE, it would become
 useful; and (and also it would not be any harmful except it is going to take this 1 page only!).

As a self-answered article I (@alwaysconfused)'ve tried to copy-paste some quick-links from search-filters. *But other users can improve it or post their 
 work as separate answers.*

How other users can improve/ contribute?

1. Other users may implement better commands to give the link a shape of button,
2. or may add a preview window, or may add more search-filters,
3. or may also help build techniques or principles to track question on other sites that don't directly tagged as bioinformatics but actually are bioinformatics questions.
4. Any other views welcome.

I think, beside ease of browse/filter;  some other advantage we'll obtain are;

1. more exchange of thoughts  between separate streams (so reduced tunnel vision). It will help find correlation between separated streams.
2. Would also help to find duplicate questions, related questions, etc.

Comment: I don't understand the question: Do you want to know where are other bioinformatic questions in order to propose to migrate from x site to Bioinformatics. Or just to have a list of sites with questions related to bioinformatics

Comment: No. Not to propose migration but just to easily find/ filter at one place @Llopis

Comment: But what do you want to "find" at those places? What do you want to filter at those places? That doesn't affect the community here (although we might be interested in answering those questions)

Comment: @Llopis You confessed, "although we might be interested in answering those questions". Yes, the linkup would promote the users of this-page to visit bioinformatics questions to other pages, and could share their views.

Comment: Also we don't browse question only for answering. We browse question for learning, isn't? so a filter must help in learning.

Comment: When I want to learn how to to X I search for X, I don't go to a page with links to informations to X,Y, and Z. Wouldn't be of more interest for people on those sites to come here on this site to ask?

Comment: Yes, and indeed a [discussion](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3705/biology-ses-place-now-bioinformatics-se-is-in-beta) is going on BioSE. Good point, but older question (those couldn't be migrated); are already have been asked; bioinformatics SE didnot born then. so to view them we might need a shortcut.

Comment: @Llopis and it would really be good if bioinformatics questions specifically asked at this site, but even after birth of this site, many bioinformatics question asked (submitted) in other SE sites, maybe many users still do not know about/ not used-to with  this site, or maybe they want a more biology/computer/other field oriented expertise. Still, if users of this-site could easily found them, (and so ways for exchange of thoughts are broadened) , it would be nice.

Comment: One simple way is to comment in all questions of each site to raise awareness of this site. Specially if someone is active in other sites

Comment: I already mentioned it in a [discussion](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3705/biology-ses-place-now-bioinformatics-se-is-in-beta/3723#3723) at BioSE. I can't alone make an action in a community, I can only express my-views. Everything else now depends on other users.

Comment: You can edit the tag, to try to redirect users, or at least let them know each time they use the tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62787/discussion-between-always-confused-and-llopis).

Comment: I also don't understand what you are suggesting here. Could you please [edit] your question and explain what your suggestion is? What does any of this have to do with the site's scope? What are you asking about (if you're asking anything)?

Comment: Also, are you just looking for https://stackexchange.com/filters/ ? You can set a tag there and it will return all questions tagged with that tag from all sites of the SE network.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list with links to the bioinformatics tag in other sites in the Stack Exchange network:

- [Biology
  site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics)
- [Cross validated
  site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics)
- [Computer science
  site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics)
- [Stack Overflow
  site](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics)